# Setting permissions through Azure DevOps API throws bad request (400)

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I'm trying to write a script to change permissions to my Azure DevOps resources using its API.

The error i get is BAD REQUEST.

My credentials are working (i'm using them in other functions to get all the parameters to build the body).

Maybe there's something wrong with the body that i'm not seeing.

This is my function:

```
function Set-Permission {
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] `
        [string]$organization,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] `
        [string]$namespaceId,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] `
        [string]$token,
        [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] `
        [string]$groupDescriptor,
        [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] `
        [int]$allowMask,
        [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $true)] `
        [int]$denyMask = 0
    )
       $body =
       @"
          {
             "token": "$token",
             "merge": true,
             "accessControlEntries": [
                {
                   "descriptor": "$groupDescriptor",
                   "allow": $allowMask,
                   "deny": $denyMask,
                   "extendedinfo": {}
                }
             ]
          }
"@
       Post-RestAPICall -url $url -body $body
}
```

These are the sample URLs and body i'm using.

URL

```
https://dev.azure.com/myAccount/_apis/accesscontrolentries/2e9eb7ed-3c0a-47d4-87c1-0ffdd275fd87?api-version=5.0
```

Body

```
"          {
             "token": "repoV2\827a6631-8685-4a0e-b53f-b54742e505fa",
             "merge": true,
             "accessControlEntries": [
                {
                   "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-828799618-2240155210-3040851271-1122305530-1-2397848184-1658408774-2559123938-1159016780",
                   "allow": 32,
                   "deny": 0,
                   "extendedinfo": {}
                }
             ]
          }"
```

The Post-RestAPICall function is just error handling for these calls.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

The token uses a regular slash (/) instead of backslash (\).

Changing that makes the request work properly.

Cheers!